# How to create formatted tooltips in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-office-2013

Some documents I saw years ago have a feature that, when a  word is`mouseovered`a small popup is displayed with info in it, and when  the mouse is moved away from the word, the small popup closes. Maybe it worked with javascript or VB but the content was unformatted *(screentip)*.
The most  intersting thing I saw is by creating [layers](https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/tooltip-for-hover-on-word) but I couldn't find how to do it in winword.

I don't necessarily need to insert bold/underlined text like on the following HTML document screenshot, but as this is for displaying some piece of code, inserted newlines/carriage returns are important.[image: from physics.se] So how I can create a formatted tooltip, or at least a tooltip where I would be able to insert newlines?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Bit of an ugly hack, and you *definately* can do better, but you'd probably want to create a hyperlink (to a bookmark, tho being lazy, I just linked it to the top).

Not being able to create newlines is probably by design, since this is sort of meant to imitate the mouseover you do on menu items or websites.

Comment: Yes, this what I mentioned in my question *(screentip)*. If you have code your readers will have to read it in one liner... :-( I'm far to create the same kind of tool tip of the picture in my question *(I recognize this is not the thing I need to do)*

Comment: Is it possible to only provide a simple screentip? I mean, no underline, no link, to jumping to another section of the document whatsoever. Only a highlighted text that shows a tip on mouse-hover.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

1)Press Ctrl+F9

2)Inside the brackets paste`AutoTextList "word seen" \s No Style \t "balloon word"`

3)Replace `word seen` and `balloon word`

4)Press F9 and the main word will disappear (with the keyboard cursor inside the brackets)

5)Press Ctrl+F9 to hide/unhide the code and leave the main word alone

Comment: How do I put images in such tooltips?