# Embed file inside Word document without icon?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2013

I'm trying to embed an email message into a word document for a weekly report.  I would like to make it more like an inline hyperlink than a document icon.  Is this possible?  I know I could link to a network share, but I would like it to be portable just in case my manager reads it offline or something.  However, with the icon, it breaks the layout.  To be specific, I have a list of "Items that need to be escalated".  They are in a bullet list.  I want to put a link to an embedded document (PDF, Excel, whatever) without having the document full of little icons.

Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [embedding](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Link-or-embed-data-cf1c1ba3-03d1-44d5-a24a-f01a752c57b5#bmwd) (not linking) the additional document to the end of your document, then using a bookmark to link to it?

Comment: Hmm, that's a neat idea and I may use it temporarily, but I don't think it's a full solution (as it would just scroll to a page that has tons of icons and they would still have to open it)

Comment: If you don't embed it with an icon, it will show the first page of the document. In that case, if it is only a single page document, they may not have to open it, but can if they choose to.

Comment: "If you don't embed it with an icon" -- That's the whole question.  How can I do this?  :D

Comment: Someone asked a similar question before. You want a link that self-references itself, like a self-contained web site. You can't do that with Word.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedding files in Word document so hyperlinks to them still works when files are moved or deleted](http://superuser.com/questions/874497/embedding-files-in-word-document-so-hyperlinks-to-them-still-works-when-files-ar)

Comment: The solution to his problem would solve my problem, but they're not the same question per se...  I don't want to link to an embedded document, I want to embed a document without the icon.  There is a difference.  In fact, when you use the "Insert > Object" menu to insert an object, there is a checkbox for "Display as icon".  I suppose I could create a transparent or tiny icon and use that so it doesn't break the layout...